# How to center the Google Map by using Iframe?

Tags: php, google-maps, dictionary, iframe

I search everywhere but i can't find a correct way to center my google map. I'm using iframe. The site is classified ads so every Ads create different location.

My code is like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" 
height="420px" width="100%" 
src="<?=Route::url('map')?>?height=400&id_ad=<?=$ad->id_ad?>&controls=0&zoom=<?=Core::config('advertisement.map_zoom')?>&get.Center=setCenter(<?=$ad->latitude?>,<?=$ad->longitude?>)">
```

Also I tried this,:

`&center=setCenter(<?=$ad->latitude?>,<?=$ad->longitude?>)`

```
&center=map.setCenter({lat:<?=$ad->latitude?>,lng:<?=$ad->longitude?>})
```

Also This,

```
setCenter(latlng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)
setCenter(latlng:<?=$ad->latitude?><?=$ad->longitude?>|<?=$ad->latitude?><?=$ad->longitude?>Literal)
```

but i can't make it right in center, it's either far more to left or far more to upper corner left. However if you open the page and you go straight to the tab "Map" you'll get it center, but if you wait then click the tap map it will not in center.

If my explanation is not very clear, please check here : https://linkinads.com/airline-job-aviation-sales-marketing-sales-representative-sales-manager/landmark-group-job-hiring-in-retail-group.html

Please Advice. Thanks

Comment: I can't use iframe taken from google.com/maps as the users are creating or evry user are located in different location. Like for example one user posted from Dubai the second from philippines... then russia..! so i cant put dubai or russia is the center of my map coordinates.

Comment: Map ScreenShot I want the marker to be in Center ! Thanks   https://i.imgur.com/40HzdHj.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the iframe it will automatically centered the location. 
eg : just visit google map (https://www.google.com/maps/)

enter your location in search bar

[image]

now press the side menu button

[image]

click on share embed map

[image]

a popup appers. click on embed map and then you can see i-frame

[image]

or if you want to centered the whole iframe then you can place iframe in a div and give it styling!

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, however my board is a classified ads. Every user have different coordinated etc. E.g someone from england posted with his address...then the other one from new york...

Comment: Okay! let say automatic will center the map...so it will be just like this? src="<?=Route::url('map')?>?height=400&id_ad=<?=$ad->id_ad?>&controls=0&zoom=<?=Core::config('advertisement.map_zoom')?>">

Comment: yes, you can try. In my case it works like that @dk-pramis

Comment: I will check that

Comment: still the same brother

Comment: I'm still trying but cant make it in center... the map location

Comment: give me a screen shot

Comment: Here is the Link of the screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/40HzdHj.png @Muhammad Shaharyar